# Greater than if_else returning wrong answer in R data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am finding a very odd issue in with my R data frame. In short, I have a formula that is supposed to compare two scores within a row and then place the winner in a column:

```
scores$Winner <- 
  ifelse(scores$Away_Score > scores$Home_Score, scores$Away_Team, scores$Home_Team)
```

This seems to work for the most part, but there is one row where the lower score, not higher score, is being reported as the winner. I have a screenshot below. The winning score is above 100 and it's the only score with triple digits, so I do wonder if that somehow is impacting it.
[image]

I haven't been able to replicate this issue outside of my actual code, so the best I can do is provide my actual code, which you can find here:

```
https://gist.github.com/jeffgswanson/6461f41c2ef1ca51e51aba3b377c9a1f
```

Thanks in advance, I'm stumped. I checked and columns are numeric. Also, I tried changing if_else to ifelse and it doesn't improve.

Comment: can you check the `str(scores)`. May be the types are not numeric?

Comment: Oh wow, yes they're 'chr'. I see what I did. In my full script I do change these to numeric but it's AFTER the new column is created, which is why when I checked before it appeared as numeric. So I need to bump this up in the order. Thanks @akrun!